# Working with pool of workers for parallel tasks

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new in Python, trying to learn about multiprocessing.

I'm trying to run the following simple script

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print(f'PID {multiprocessing.current_process().pid}')
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:         # start 4 worker processes
        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))       # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

I'm expecting to see prints with 4 different PIDs, since I started the pool with processes=4.

But, I see all the prints with the same PID.

output:

```
PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

PID 7412

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

what I'm missing with my understanding of pool?

Comment: this works for me using Python 3.10 under Linux 5.19.  i.e. I get multiple distinct PIDs printed

Comment: just thought this might be due to processes taking a while to "get ready" to start taking requests.  you could put `time.sleep(0.1)` in `f` to give other processes time to start

Comment: pool makes no guarantee that the work will be done across multiple workers, it just guarantees that the work will be done as fast as it can, so a worker might take all of the work if the work is small enough like just returning the number squared.

Comment: I tried to add sleep as  Sam recommended- it helped. good enough for this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be due to the tasks taking less time to perform than it takes for different worker processes to start accepting work.  This seems like desirable behavior as the aim of multiprocessing `Pool`s is to dispatch work as quickly as possible, if one process is ready first then it seems reasonable to dispatch everything to it.

I see this happening more reliably when spawning processes rather than forking (Linux uses fork by default, Windows can only spawn workers).

By changing the `sleep` and `start_method` it's possible to see these effects:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process, set_start_method
from collections import Counter
from time import sleep
from random import random

# force some processes to take longer to start
sleep(random() * 0.1)

def f(_):
    sleep(0.01) # make the task take >10ms to complete
    return current_process().pid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # force workers to be spawned rather than forked under Unix OSs
    set_start_method("spawn")
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        print(Counter(pool.map(f, range(10))))
```

Under Linux 5.19, creating processes by forking is at least 30x faster than spawning.  The more work you do at the top-level the worse it gets, just an `import numpy` makes spawning 100x worse.

To see the difference in start methods I used the following:

```
# import numpy as np

def main():
    # import in function to minimise spawn time, annoyingly this doesn't have
    # much noticable effect
    from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method
    from sys import argv
    from time import monotonic

    set_start_method(argv[1])

    # run it a few times, the first run is always worse
    results = []
    for _ in range(10):
        t0 = monotonic()
        p = Process()
        p.start()
        p.join()
        results.append(monotonic() - t0)

    for dt in results:
        print(f"{dt*1000:.3f}ms")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For reference, the results on my laptop with Python 3.10.7 and Linux 5.19.11 are:

```
> echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
> python fork_vf_spawn.py spawn | tail -3
34.456ms
34.562ms
34.089ms
> python fork_vf_spawn.py fork | tail -3
1.074ms
1.258ms
1.133ms
```

Changing the CPU frequency governor helps minimise differences due to dynamic changes in response to changes in workload.  Uncommenting the `import numpy` line results in spawn going up to ~110ms.

Comment: If worker function `f` is sleeping *sufficiently* , then I would think you don't need for every process to first sleep .1 seconds before processing. If the second pool process starts up N seconds after the first pool process to start, then if they both first sleep .1 seconds before processing, won't the second process still start processing N seconds after the first one? And it shouldn't make a difference whether processes are started by *spawn* or *fork*. On my desktop .01 seconds turns out to be sufficient for both Windows and WSL Debian using *fork* to produce the same results.

Comment: the `sleep`s were just to demonstrate the issue, i.e. random sleep to make some processes take longer to get ready.  `spawn`ing processes will take much longer than `fork`ing (e.g. modules will need to be imported again) hence any random differences in timing will get increased as well.

Comment: @Booboo was interested to see how much difference there was between fork and spawn.  benchmark results show that spawn takes longer than I was expecting, but makes more sense why a `Pool` only checks for process termination every 100ms.